# Measure between two hex values

Tags: color, measurement, hex

I was curious to know if anyone has used or seen code to measure colors between two hex values.  Any language will do but I did see the JavaScript source to determine what HEX value is in RGB.

Example: between `#44aaee` and `#0088ee` would result in `#2199ee`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a shell script to handle it. I quickly type the alias to my script followed by the two colors in question (without the hash mark) and it spits out the result.

```
E_INVALID_ARGUMENTS=2;

usage()
{
  echo -e "Usage: ${COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE}$(basename $0)${COLOR_END} color color"
  exit $1
}

if [ -f "${HOME}/bin/colors" ]; then . "${HOME}/bin/colors"; fi
OPTIONS="ibase=16;obase=10;";

if [ -z "$1" ]; then usage $E_INVALID_ARGUMENTS; fi
if [ -z "$2" ]; then usage $E_INVALID_ARGUMENTS; fi

CA=$(echo "$1" | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]);
CB=$(echo "$2" | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]);

C1=$(echo "${OPTIONS}(${CA:0:2}+${CB:0:2})/2" | bc);
C2=$(echo "${OPTIONS}(${CA:2:2}+${CB:2:2})/2" | bc);
C3=$(echo "${OPTIONS}(${CA:4:2}+${CB:4:2})/2" | bc);
```